# Using @PatchRequest to update only certain fields

Tags: spring, rest, api

I have tried to test my API using @PatchRequest and I get the following error.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/intranet-api] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute batch; SQL [update portal.dbo.DANCE_MASTER set name=?, age=?, gender=?, grade=?,status=?, updated_by=?, updated_ts=? where id=?]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch] with root cause
    java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'name', table 'ctcportal1.dbo.DANCE_MASTER'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
```

From the error shown, it seems like I should provide updated values for all fields. However, I only want to update certain fields in the table.

Answer (score 0):

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column
>   'name', table 'ctcportal1.dbo.DANCE_MASTER'; column does not allow
>   nulls. UPDATE fails.

Error message clearly says that, *Cannot insert the value NULL into column'name'*. 
Check the DANCE_MASTER table definition and provide values for all required columns.

You could also the values by running following query against database. Replace the question marks with appropriate values.

```
update portal.dbo.DANCE_MASTER 
set name=?, 
age=?, 
gender=?, 
grade=?,
status=?, 
updated_by=?, 
updated_ts=? 
where id=?
```

Comment: Hi, but i only want to update certain fields, not all fields. May I know how I can do it. That is my reason for using patchRequest instead of using putRequest or PostRequest.

Comment: then share the code related to spring dao code related updating record.